# Is it possible to have SQL Like Clause in Neo4J CQL?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

At present the implementation is

```
MATCH (emp:Employee) 
WHERE emp.name = 'Abc'
RETURN emp
```

Is it possible to have a like clause e.g.

```
 MATCH (emp:Employee) 
WHERE emp.name Like %'Abc'%
RETURN emp
```

like the way we have in SQL ?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, with a regular expression(see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#query-where-regex)

```
MATCH (emp:Employee) 
WHERE emp.name =~ '.*Abc.*'
RETURN emp
```

or with CONTAINS (case sensitive) (see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#query-where-string)

```
 MATCH (emp:Employee) 
 WHERE emp.name CONTAINS 'Abc'
 RETURN emp
```

CONTAINS is available in Neo4j 2.3.x

Comment: for case insensitive regexp use '(?i).*abc.*'